# Rise and fall timings of a pulse generator

Tags: waveform

In a digital programmable or static device, does the rise and fall timings and waveforms of a square pulse obey the reimann sum when observed at much higher resolutions?

If sampling rate of this device or some other DAC, a higher sampling rate scope or observer measures the signal at better precision then the output device can generate. I just want to know the experts' opinion on this because my favourite scope is in the office now and I can not measure it. Is it reimann sum or something like an exponential behavioral ?

Answer (score 0):

From  Hartley's  Law relating Analog \$ f_{-3dB}\$ and Digital \$f_{Rate}\$ Bandwidth \$f_{BW}\$ (= 0.35/rise time) and number of bits N per sample. Sometimes shown as follows;

\$ f_{Rate} = 2*f_{-3dB_{BW}} \cdot log_2(N) =6.02f_{-3dB_{BW}} *log_{10}\cdot (N)\$

- let N=10 bits with resolution of 1/1024 as your "precision"
- if your message   is a square wave is 1MHz and BW desired is 300MHz or ~1ns rise time then ADC sampling rate must be >>6.02*300MHz*log10= 1.8GHz

A Bessel filter must attenuate >60 dB ~ 900 MHz for aliasing < resolution since N=10 implies 60 dB range and 900MHz is 1/2 sampling rate but has -3dB BW of 300MHz  thus >= 6th order LPF.

**I'm not sure how you wanted to do a Reimann Sum on an exponential signal.

Comment: Thanks for the writing then I think there might be a typo. Sampling rate you acquire is derived from the nyquist and was given at the times when digital systems were not around thus might not be suitable to be used in this case. Filter does apply dependent on your probe cable geometry at the time of measurement aspecially around these certain thresholds where you push the limits of your bench setup. Your numbers look correct to me. I come to a conclusion that all our theoretical derivations are supported by our devices outputs which are completely non-stochastic at certain decimals thus...

Comment: An analog-digital conversion scheme should introduce a continuous behavioral such as an exponential when converted to LSB digital format where precision/resolution/timing of your instrument beats the fundamental behavior of the physical govarnance and can supply you data that is far beyond the continuous description yielded to the design of the idea of the instrument itself. I tried to express as clear as I can due to my humble knowledge.

Comment: I attempted to prove your question using Hartley's law for Digital/Analog ratios with resolution.  In old analog days it was Bits/Baud now bits per DSO sample.  The Nyquist filter depends on ripple, slope, group delay and order of filter but essentially can vary, so with 2 or 20 bit resolution you get a different result

Comment: Hartley defined this well before Shannon et al who developed the communication laws of probability, SNR, BER and bits/baud yet BW*rise time is a constant.